# Canvas Re-sizing -IOS HTML5 App - (Chart JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

I'm having a strange intermittent issue with Chart JS (http://www.chartjs.org/) within a html5 IOS app.

I have defined my canvas as listed here -

```
 <canvas id="overallChart" height="270" width="270" style="height:270px!important; width:270px!important;"></canvas>
```

There are multiple charts in a page - the charts are triggered via a basic chart js settings -

```
 var lineData = {
labels : ["Jan","Feb","March","April","May"],
datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(255,128,38,0.9)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(225,225,225,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(225,225,225,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [65,59,90,81,56]
    },
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(119,62,20,0.9)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(225,225,225,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(225,225,225,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [28,48,40,19,96]
    }
]
 }

 var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineData)
```

Despite the inline Important style - the canvas randomly draws out a huge version of the chart and alters the height /width values.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour?  Any suggestions to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same/similar problem and found a solution: the problem arose when re-drawing on a previously used canvas (re-drawing to incorporate new user-input data, or drawing a different type of chart, for example). Drawing on a 'fresh' canvas never caused scaling issues.

Therefore, the solution is to replace the used canvas with a new one, before drawing on it. In jQuery:

```
$("#overallChart").replaceWith("<canvas id='overallChart' height='270' width='270'></canvas>");
var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("overallChart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineData);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript you are trying to select the element with the id of 'lineChart', but in your HTML you are giving the element an id of 'overallChart'. Change:

```
var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineData)
```

to:

```
var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("overallChart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineData)
```

to

```
var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineData);
```

and see if that works for you.